# Setting up Locomotive Engine Gone horribly wrong

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

So I have installed this twice now and still have the same error

I run mongod

I run unicorn

it tells me to create and account,

i create the account

log in

then Sass::SyntaxError in Locomotive/pages#index

Showing /Users/jorybraun/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/locomotive_cms-2.4.1/app/views/locomotive/shared/_head.html.haml where line #14 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/transform-legacy.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/jorybraun/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/locomotive_cms-2.4.1/app/assets/stylesheets/locomotive/backoffice/menu/main.css.scss)
  /Users/jorybraun/sites/jancms/jancms/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/jorybraun/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  (in /Users/jorybraun/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/locomotive_cms-2.4.1/app/assets/stylesheets/locomotive/backoffice/menu/main.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #14):

11:   :plain
12:     window.Locomotive = { mounted_on: '#{Locomotive.mounted_on}' }
13: 
14: = stylesheet_link_tag     'locomotive', media: 'screen'
15: = javascript_include_tag  'locomotive'
16: 
17: = render 'locomotive/shared/main_app_head_before_backbone'
Trace of template inclusion: /Users/jorybraun/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/locomotive_cms-2.4.1/app/views/locomotive/layouts/application.html.haml

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I solved it by adding the following line to my project's Gemfile:

```
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.7'
```

Apparently there is some kind of bug in compass 1.0.1, and assets won't precompile. This line forces the version of compass to be 0.12.x, so add this in, run

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

... and you should be good to go.